# How to used mysql variable in laravel?

Tags: mysql, laravel-5, public-key-encryption

I want to set this mysql variable in laravel controller method.

***SET block_encryption_mode = 'AES-256-ECB' ;***

Please help me out,I apologize in advance for some mistake in asking question.

Comment: What are you expecting `clinician_credential()` to return?

Comment: want clinician_credential tbl data and also if possible then with user data also

Comment: What model is `clinician_credential()` on? `User`?

Comment: Documents model

Comment: This is just a many to many relationship with `clinitian_credentials` essentially being the pivot table. `ClinicianCredentials` shouldn't exist as a model.

Comment: @apokryfos hasOneThrough not possible?

Comment: I don't think it's an appropriate relationship here.

Comment: any of solution without pivot table to using relationship

Comment: I don't want to use for each loop